# Allow user type specific keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table in which I want to allow users edit an specific cell, the problem is that they only can type 1, 3, 5 or 9, others numbers and text are not allowed. Also, when user change the current value in that cell and press Enter I'm going to update that value using back-end (for this there is no problem). At the moment I have a code that doesn't allow user type other different numbers from above. But this code has some bugs, for example: if I change the value from the cell and then I press Enter the value is not updated and also when the blur/lost focus/leave event happens the value is changed to 0 automatically but this only happen in my app. Because in [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mzdyRy?editors=1010) works fine. I tried with different browsers and the same happen.

Here is the code snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#TableBody').on('keydown', '.number', function (e) {
    var curVal = $(this).text();
    if (e.which == 13) {
      alert("Valor " + curVal);
      $(this).text(curVal);
      $(this).trigger('blur');
    }
    else {
      if (e.which == 49 || e.which == 97 || e.which == 53 || e.which == 101 || e.which == 57 || e.which == 105 || e.which == 51 || e.which == 99) {
        $(this).text("");
      } else {
        NivelAct = curVal;
        $(this).text("");
        $(this).trigger('blur');
      }
    }
  });
  
    $('#TableBody').on('blur', '.number', function () {
      var curVal = $(this).text();
      console.log(curVal);
      if (curVal != 1 || curVal != 3 || curVal != 5 != curVal != 9) {
        $(this).text(curVal);
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-striped- table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <td>ID</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="TableBody">
    <tr>
      <td>IRD-1</td>
      <td class="number" contenteditable>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>IRD-2</td>
      <td class="number" contenteditable>10</td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You did hear of `[1,3,5,9].includes(e.key)`?

Comment: @connexo Nop, I don't have any idea of that. Should I use it on keydown event instead of if statement?

Comment: You might want to read into it. `Array.prototype.includes()`.